# Is it possible to un-resolve a conflict in SVN?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn

I went to commit some changes to some units tests.  My coworker had committed some tests to the same file prior to me, so when I did an SVN up, the test file was in conflict.

I tried to do a merge with TortoiseMerge, but there were just line after line of question marks for the conflicts, so there appeared to be no way to merge.

OK, no problem, I'll just edit around the conflicts by cutting my work out of the file with the intention of pasting it in below his after the resolution. This is where I got into trouble.  I didn't realize the extent of the changes that would happen when I allowed AnkhSVN to use his changes instead of mine, and have apparently lost a couple of hours of work because I didn't copy enough of what was to get changed.  This is just inexperience on my part and I think I know what to do in the future (copy the whole file prior to the resolution so I can get my work out of it if it becomes necessary).

This [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012810/svn-keeps-corrupting-files-with-mine-how-to-fix) and this [TortoiseSVN article](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html) (we use both AnkhSVN & TortoiseSVN), talks about the conflict files, which I can't find anywhere in the project, either locally or in the repository.  They preserve the state of my changes (.mine), his committed changes (.rNEWREV or the HEAD version), and the previous version (.rOLDREV).  I suspect the files are deleted when the resolution occurs?  Is there any way to un-resolve the files so I can retrieve my work?

In this case it won't take me too long to recreate the work, but I'd like to know if it's possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the merge tool you used, you might find the original files locally. Look for files with the same file name, but different extensions (such as .rREV or .orig).

Comment: Would those be in the same directory as the project?  That's where I'd expect them, but I can look higher in the directory structure.  EDIT:  I've looked higher in the tree inside my general projects folder and not found anything there either.

Comment: They would be in the same directory as the files. I use KDiff3 (which can be used as merge tool in TortoiseSVN and AnkhSVN), which creates the .orig files if called.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm currently using WinMerge, which I like, but maybe I'll try KDiff3.  I've recreated the stuff I lost yesterday.  It's sounding like lesson learned, don't do that.

Comment: I use both: WinMerge is usually better for diffing, since I can directly edit the diffed files. However, it doesn't do a three-way compare, which is much better when merging. For that, I use KDiff3 (which also handles diffs where mostly whitespace changed better).