# Jenkins doesn't compile project

Tags: .net, jenkins, svn, msbuild, tortoisesvn

I have problem with using Jenkins. I have SVN repository which contains my solution. First time when I compiled my code via Jenkns MSBuild without any error. After some app upgrades I have tried to compile my project again. I have got following error in three projects:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4381,5): error MSB3541: Files has invalid value "<<<<<<< .mine". Illegal characters in path. [C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\***\***\**\DAL.csproj]`

I have tried to delete `obj` folders, recreate project in repo, use older version and that's still didn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `<<<<<<< .mine` is due to a merge conflict with SVN. You may have edited a file in your SVN repository and when Jenkins or you did an Update it couldn't update due to conflicts so it made the intermediate file you see. Some more info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012810/svn-keeps-corrupting-files-with-mine-how-to-fix

Comment: I found the purpose of the problem.  There was a conflict not on my pc/snv. Jenkins updated badly project files and created in workspace some files with unresolved conflict. Thanks.